# Android file is always created as a directory

Tags: android, file, filenotfoundexception

When I try to create an internal file in my Android app, the file created is always a directory. I saw a similar post and apparently the way they solved the issue was by calling `mkdirs()` on the parent directory of the file. However, that didn't work for me. I've tried adding a slash to the beginning of the file's name, adding a slash after, doing both, and I've also tried adding an extension such as `.txt` to the file name. No matter what I do, the resulting file is always a directory, not a writable or readable file. The code below is located in my main activity class, hence the `getFilesDir()` call.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

// always logs "false"
public void createFile() {
  File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "myFile");

  try {
    file.createNewFile();
    Log.i("" + file.isFile())
  } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("The file might no exist.")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of the File constructor ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)))

> the child pathname string is taken to denote either a directory or a file.

So if your file name has no extension, then it will be create as a directory

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `createNewFile()` was doing nothing because I had created the file as a directory the first time I tested the code. Since then, I was just referencing the folder I had previously created every time I ran. Once I called `delete()` on the file once, creating it again with an extension in the name properly created the file.